# RoundCube SSL SMTP Failure

Tags: smtp, roundcube

I've set up a roundcube installation on my website that works great when using SSL for IMAP and non-ssl for smtp.  The only problem is this: when I switch to using `ssl://smtp.[mydomain].com` for my smtp server, I get this error in the log file:

> SMTP Error: SMTP error: Connection failed: Failed to connect socket: Connection refused in [path]/program/lib/Roundcube/rcube.php on line 1504 (POST [path]/?_task=mail&_unlock=loading1404435957595&_lang=en?_task=mail&_action=send)

Now when I put the same configuration into my phone mail client, I could send via ssl, so the SMTP server is working over port 465.  I can' get it figured out, and I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Quick check, from roundcube server, can you telnet to `smtp.[mydomain].com` port 465?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to check the connection and opened tcp port by doing `telnet smtp.[mydomain].com 465` directly from your box where you have RoundCube running.
Also, please make sure you have openssl enabled in your php.